# parsing the Json for the Optional fields

Tags: python, json, regex

I have the JSON in the below format:

```
{  
    "type":"MetaModel",
    "attributes":[  
        {  
            "name":"Code",
            "regexp":"^[A-Z]{3}$"
        },
        {
            "name":"DefaultDescription",
        },
   ]
}
```

The `attributes["regexp"]` is optional.  When I try to access the field like `attribute["regexp"]` , I'm getting the error as

```
KeyError: 'regexp'
```

The assumption is, if the field is not there then it will be considered as NULL.

How can I access the optional fields?

Comment: `attributes[0]["regexp"]`

Comment: You can do it with attributes.get('regexp'). It returns None if the key is not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `attributes[0]['regexp']` because regexp is inside attribtues list

Answer (score 17):

Use `get`, a method of dictionaries that will return `None` if a key doesn't exist:

```
foo = json.loads(the_json_string)
value = foo.get('regexp')
if value:
   # do something with the regular expression
```

You can also just catch the exception:

```
value = None
try:
    value = foo['regexp']
except KeyError:
    # do something, as the value is missing
    pass
if value:
    # do something with the regular expression
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    >>>data = {  
"type":"MetaModel",
"attributes":[  
    {  
        "name":"Code",
        "regexp":"^[A-Z]{3}$"
    },
    {
        "name":"DefaultDescription",
    },
]
}
    >>>>c = data['attributes'][0].get('regexp')
    >>>>print c # >>> '^[A-Z]{3}$'
```